# Vaadin combobox separator

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm currently developing a Vaadin app, and I've arrived to the need of a `ComboBox` with some separators between items. I've been looking arround and it seems currently there is no way to achieve this.

Being more specific:

- **What do I mean with *separator*?** A separator is an item in the `ComboBox` that, presumably, cannot be selected. The caption of this item should be customizable, to achieve something like this effect: **Section 1** *Thing 1, Thing 2* **Section 2** *Thing 3, Thing 4*
- ***Must it be bold?*** Nope, it's just an example. I could use something like "*-- Section 1 --*", there is no problem there.
- As the main idea is using a `ComboBox`, **any answer should provide at least the same functionalities** as it. *ie: filtering, adding elements...*

*What I've tried so far:*
I overwrote `setInternalValue` method of the `ComboBox`, to not be able to select a separator like this:

```
public class ComboBoxWithSeparators() {
    @Override
    protected void setInternalValue(Object newValue) {
        Object oldValue = super.getValue();
        if(isSeparator)
            super.setInternalValue(oldValue);
        else
            super.setInternalValue(newValue);
    }
}
```

This kinda works, but when you select a separator, it is shown by a fraction of a second in the selected box, then is overriden by the old element.
**So, my actual question is:** *Is there a way to not enable selecting an item within the `ComboBox`*?

*Related:* [Add an item in `ComboBox` and disable it with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42979261/6381179)

Comment: I think you should use the NativeSelect component to handle this. It's one of the missing parts in Vaadin, a DropDown where you can define Separators/Groups and Enabled/Disable individual items

Comment: @AndréSchild Could you elaborate it more, or link an example? I'm looking at [Vaadin 7 NativeSelect API](https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.7/com/vaadin/ui/NativeSelect.html) and I don't see anything like *define separators/groups* or *enable/disable* items.

Comment: It does not exist. But I think the post you refenced in your initial question is valid for the NativeSelect component

Comment: Maybe you can use a [menu bar](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/interaction/menu-bar) instead? This should support both simple dividers as well as disabled items (see *Item 1* menu from the link). Furthermore, if you want sections, you could group your items into more sub-menus to make the most of the real-estate and easier for the user to track.

Comment: @Morfic Well, That could be an option if there aren't many entries in a category, but it doesn't support filtering, which is why I was thinking in `ComboBox` in the first place. I think I will use an `OptionGroup` as a category selector, given that I can't think any other solution

Comment: Or 2 _linked_ combos for category and sub-category, now that you've added fitlering to the list of requirements

Comment: @Morfic That's right. I'll edit  the question and make a communiti-wiki answer with this workarounds. Feel free to add anything you think about this.

Comment: @Shirkam I just published a component for vaadin 8 which does this https://vaadin.com/directory/component/nativeselectext7---nativeselectext7-add-on/1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to obtain such thing as a `ComboBox` with separators in Vaadin, but there are some workarounds that can be used instead of that:

- [Menu bar](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/components/components-menubar.html):

[image: Vaadin Menu bar]
This component supports separators, categories and enabling/disabling items. The con is that it doesn't allow filtering like `ComboBox`, but you can add shortcuts for usual selections.

- Anidated `ComboBox`:
  [image: Anidated <code>ComboBox</code>]
  This way you can filter by types or/and item, but you can't see every item you have, as they are filtered by categories/types. Of course, you can add a category that includes all elements to bypass this limitation.
- `ComboBox` with no-selectable items:
  This workaround acts like an usual `ComboBox`, but you are overriding `#setInternalValue` to make certain elements unselectable like:

  ```
  public class ComboBoxWithSeparators() {
      @Override
      protected void setInternalValue(Object newValue) {
          Object oldValue = super.getValue();
          if(isSeparator(newValue))
              super.setInternalValue(oldValue);
          else
              super.setInternalValue(newValue);
      }
  }
  ```

The problem here is that you can *actually* select separators, but the `#setInternalValue` override will restore the old element. This may cause odd behaviour.

- @AndréSchild [nativeSelectExt7](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/nativeselectext7---nativeselectext7-add-on/1.0):
  This option provides the same functionality as *`ComboBox` with no-selectable items* but is better as it highlights disabled items, and fully disallows selecting one of them.
  [image: NativeSelectExt7]

Answer (score 0):

There is a code example for non selectable separators here: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18441538/vaadin-14-combo-box-with-nonselectable-separators

The trick is to ...

- (a) disable the (nonselectable) option component (just for visualisation)
- (b) extend the valueChangeListener so that it clears the ComboBox whenever a user selects a nonselectable option.

It looks like this:

[image: ComboBox with separators]